# Google map's polylines not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polyline

I am trying to add polylines to a map but they are not appearing when called to do so

Here is some of my code:

```
var waypts = [];
var plyLine;
   function initialize() {

    plyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: waypts,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
    });   
}
```

This function is called in an onclick listener

```
function setWaypts()
{
    waypts = [];
    plyLine.setMap(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < (poiArrayList.length); i++) {
            waypts.push(new google.maps.LatLng(poiArrayList[i].mark.getPosition().lat(), poiArrayList[i].mark.getPosition().lng()))             
        };  
    plyLine.setMap(map);
}
```

This is what the log(mark.getPosition()) prints out:

Uncaught Error: (51.88804094128838, -8.506078720092773)

Can anybody stop if I did something wrong with my code?

```
    function poi(id, name, description, mark, inv) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.mark = mark;
        this.inv = inv;
    }
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            draggable: false,
            map: map,
            id: markerId,
            icon: iconUrl
        });
```

Comment: What is marker?  It appears there is more code then what you've put in your question.

Comment: There is a lot more code but I tried to cut out as much as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(poiArrayList[i].mark.getPosition())
```

A [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object takes two numbers as arguments.  Simplest fix is it looks like `mark.getPosition()` is already a google.maps.LatLng, just use that.

Or create a new one like this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(poiArrayList[i].mark.getPosition().lat(), poiArrayList[i].mark.getPosition().lng())
```

Comment: Ok they seem to be adding to the waypts array ok but the polylines are still not displaying on the map.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or a link to a map that exhibits the problem?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: genRoute is not defined ` What is genRoute?

Comment: I had directions service in before but I removed it that is an old function that I do not use anymore. I don't know what I did but it is working now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Could you please fix the fiddle and remove extraneous code?  How is it supposed to work?  How does the code to draw the polyline get called?  I was assuming I needed to click a button.

Comment: I got it working, I can upload the solution if you would like?

Comment: Is it just http://jsfiddle.net/PWRWc/5/?  Or did you make the polylines follow the roads?

Comment: They can go off road, it is part of a self guided tour of a city. I removed the directions service because there can only be 10 points with that and the user may wish to go another route other than the best way auto selected by the directions service.